# Windows Terminal - open new tab with current environment

Tags: windows, terminal, tabs, new-operator, environment

I'd like to open a new Command Prompt tab in Windows Terminal (`wt.exe`) with the environment that has been prepared/modified in the current tab, but each time I open a new tab using `wt.exe nt` a "brand new" tab is created.

Even duplicating an existing tab via `Ctrl+Shift+D` doesn't "really" duplicate it but creates a brand new instance.

I also can't find any other way to pre-define environment variables. Also it's not possible to run a script to set the environment prior to another command while creating that new tab like `wt.exe nt "set_env.cmd && launch.exe"`.

With the old Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) that was not a problem; starting a `cmd.exe` within a `cmd.exe` inherits the environment from its ancestor and in combination with `start` it opened a new window.

Within a wt.exe:

```
> set foo=bar
> echo %foo%
bar
> wt.exe new-tab
> echo %foo%
Environment variable foo not defined
```

Within cmd.exe

```
> set foo=bar
> echo %foo%
bar
> start cmd.exe
> echo %foo%
bar
```